# Using Solve to find value of this function?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, numerical-integration

I'm looking to find the x value of function PotentialProfileCurve1 when it is equal to 1. What do I need to do to get a numerical solution out of applying solve to this function?

```
s2[x_] = NDSolve[{Vsemi'[x] == -((V3 - V1)/Abs[V3 - V1]) (p2*( 
              (nb*(Exp[-zn*Vsemi[x]*q2])) +
             (pb*(Exp[-zp*Vsemi[x]*q2])) +
             (-zNd*NdZnO*Vsemi[x]*q2) - (nb + pb)))^(1/2), 
    Vsemi[0] == V3 - V1}, Vsemi, {x, 0, 1000*10^-9}, 
   MaxSteps -> 100000];

PotentialProfileCurve1[x_] = Evaluate[Vsemi[x] /. s2[x]];

Solve[PotentialProfileCurve1[x] == 1, x]
```

Instead of outputting a numerical value, i get this output:

```
 {{x -> InverseFunction[                                 -6
         InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 1. 10  }}, <>], 1, 1][1]}}
```

the function looks like this: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5euG.png)

Comment: I think you can just apply `N` to that result to request a numerical value, or you could have used `NSolve` or `FindRoot` to begin with.

Comment: if that doesn't help, you should supply values for your parameters so others can reproduce the result.